# Set notations problem

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to write that y contains the elements a,b and c and that y is a subset of x and that x contains {a, b, c} and d and e. However, my latex code doesn't parse. I have been trying this for hours and have tried different spacing, alternate notation but none of it has worked. Can someone please tell me how to amend it. Thank you.

My code:

```
$latex y = \{ {a ,b ,c}\}\newline  y\subseteq x\newline  x = \{ {\{{a, b, c}\}, d, e, f}\} $
```

FYI, latex has worked before.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It still parses and is printing the result expected. The Word **latex** should be removed however in that line, which is a question of style, but it doesn't make the code fail

Comment: It does not parse for me. I am using wordpress.

Comment: Well, this is about `TeX/LaTeX` etc. and not `WordPress`. Perhaps, WordPress has something like an `LaTeX` interpreter internally?

Comment: the rest of the latex i have been using works. Did it work straight off? Did you  change any of my code?

Comment: No, I did not. I just copied your line **as is** and it worked out of the box, in a MWE.

Comment: Are the dollar signs correctly placed?

Comment: Wordpress has some limitations on the sort of TeX code it can accept. It might be inappropriate for this web site to ask for help with the shortcomings of Wordpress.

Comment: @SamuelBird: Perhaps, you should make a clear statement in your question text that your `TeX` code does not work within `WordPress`, otherwise the question is somewhat misleading.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress and not TeX and friends

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$y = \{ {a ,b ,c}\}\newline  y\subseteq x\newline  x = \{ {\{{a, b, c}\}, d, e, f}\} $
\end{document}
```

Works fine.

[image: the result of the compilation, cropped to fit]

Comment: Does your solution also work in WordPress?

Comment: It should be stated, that the original question used somewhat 'inline' `TeX` code for `WordPress` but fails there. This answer is correct in the sense of `TeX`  usage itself, but has no direct connection to the `WordPress` feature, which is of course not topic of TeX.SE.

Comment: Why not \noindent after \begin{document}? Is \newline the best solution here to do linebreak?

Comment: @MattAllegro **`\newline` is NEVER a good solution** for a line break in an equation. Please use the `amsmath` multiline equation environments, such as `align`, `gather`, `multline` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Online Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) I could use the following [formula](http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=%5Cbegin%7Baligned%7Dy%20%26%3D%20%5C%7Ba%20%2Cb%20%2Cc%5C%7D%5C%5C%20y%20%26%5Csubseteq%20x%5C%5C%20x%20%26%3D%20%5C%7B%5C%7Ba%2C%20b%2C%20c%5C%7D%2C%20d%2C%20e%2C%20f%5C%7D%20%5Cend%7Baligned%7D), for example:

```
\begin{aligned}y &= \{a ,b ,c\}\\ y& \subseteq x\\ x &= \{\{a, b, c\}, d, e, f\} \end{aligned}
```

> [image: Result]

I assume they are using WordPress, but the documentation about the internals are quite sparse.

BTW, the math is wrong. *y* is not a subset of *x*, but an element.

Comment: @Dennis: Set `x` consists of the elements `{a,b,c}` (also a set can be an element), `d`, `e`, and `f`. Since `y` is `{a,b,c}`, it is an element of `x`. `y` would be a subset of `x`, it is would be `{{a,b,c}}` (a set that contains another set as element).